# Using tkinter buttons to execute another script

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, camera, raspberry-pi

I have been writing a few programs for the raspberry pi camera, namely one that just shows the camera output, one that takes a picture and then applies face recognition and so on. I got most of these working but I am having trouble incorporating all these into 1 program.

What I'm thinking is just simple buttons than when pressed will execute the associated python script, for simplicity sake lets say I just want to execute the simplest one, just the output of the camera. I have the code written like this.

```
import cv2
import time
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera

camera =PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(320, 240)
camera.framerate=30
rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 240))

time.sleep(1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr" , 
use_video_port=True):

image=frame.array


cv2.imshow("Faces" , image)
key = cv2.waitKey(1)

rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Now I have another code, done mostly in tkinter thats just the buttons that call the code to execute the camera script. I want it to look something like this.

```
from Tkinter import *

def executeCameraScript():
    #Code for the camera script to trigger
def option2():
    #x
def option3():
    #y



root = Tk()
frame= Frame(root)
frame.pack()


button=Button(frame,
              text="Turn on the Camera",
              command=executeCameraScript)
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button=Button(frame,
              text="Option3",
              command=option2)
button.pack(side=LEFT)
button=Button(frame,
              text="Option3",
              command=option3)
button.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

My question is what should I use so that when I press the Turn on the Camera button , it executes the camera script (preferably without closing the button frame so I can close the script from there as well) , is there any simple way to do this ?

Comment: in other script you could put code in functions and then you can `import` this file like other modules, and run functions from this script.

Comment: you can also use module `subprocess` to run any program.

Comment: BTW: if other script runs long then it will block main script so it will freeze - so you will have to use module `threading` to run it in thread`

Comment: you could always turn it into a function?

Comment: I tried that but had no luck implementing it , as far as i know function can only return a value so how should I go about doing it ?

Comment: function is not problem. With code in function you can control when you run it. Problem is that your script is long-running program so it will block tkinter - you will have to run it in thread.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly `os.system` should do the trick. https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/620147-how-execute-python-script-another-python-script

Comment: Thank you all for the help ! I managed to get it kinda working by doing what was suggested here , using the first script as a function and then calling it in a new thread . The output of the camera works just fine and i can even move the frame with the buttons , so it is not frozen but all of the buttons disappear , is there something i did wrong ? I can post the code if needed.

Comment: @Liqkerin That would be another question.

Comment: @Liqkerin If this question is answered please provide the answer, ideally as community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you mean but you can do it like this:

```
from tkinter import *
def Script():
    #Insert your script here

button = Button(root, text = "Launch Script", command = Script)
```